# JQuery | Revealing a block of text on click. Need div to be above img, z-index does not work

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical line of images of planets. What I am trying to do is when the row, defined by a div tag, is clicked upon a block of text will appear. I have it somewhat working. Currently it will recognize I am clicking in the div, but only if I'm not on top of the img tag. However, I've set the z-index lower than the div.

What I have so far:

HTML

```
<article id="planets" class="article articleTwo">
    <div id="sun" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
         <img src="images/sun.png" alt="The Sun"/>
    </div>
    <div id="mercury" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
         <img src="images/mercury.png" alt="Mercury"/>
    </div>
    <div id="venus" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/venus.png" alt="Venus"/>
    </div>
    <div id="earth" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/earth.png" alt="Earth"/>
    </div>
    <div id="mars" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/mars.png" alt="Mars"/>
    </div>
    <div id="jupiter" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/jupiter.png" alt="Jupiter"/>
    </div>
    <div id="saturn" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/saturn.png" alt="Saturn"/>
    </div>
    <div id="uranus" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/uranus.png" alt="Uranus"/>
    </div>
    <div id="neptune" class="off" onclick="planetClick()">
        <img src="images/neptune.png" alt="Neptune"/>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article.articleTwo img {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    z-index: -2;
}

article.articleTwo div {
    overflow: auto;
}

.off {
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color .4s ease;
}

.hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color .4s ease;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function planetClick() {
    if ($(event.target).not("img").hasClass("hover")) {
        $(event.target).not("img").removeClass("hover");
        $(event.target).not("img").addClass("off");
    }
    else {
     $(event.target).not("img").addClass("hover");
        $(event.target).not("img").removeClass("off");
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand the problem since the code is hard to test. But the z-index won't work since the img is inside the div so they are on a different layer. I only can imagine that the div is maybe smaller then the image inside. You could try to change overflow auto to hidden.

```
article.articleTwo div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I would also change my setup a little bit. Since your element can only be "hover" or "off" and they all start with "off" i don't think you need it.

```
<article id="planets" class="article articleTwo">
    <div id="sun">
         <img src="images/sun.png" alt="The Sun"/>
    </div>
    <div id="mercury">
         <img src="images/mercury.png" alt="Mercury"/>
    </div>
    <div id="venus">
        <img src="images/venus.png" alt="Venus"/>
    </div>
    <div id="earth">
        <img src="images/earth.png" alt="Earth"/>
    </div>
    <div id="mars">
        <img src="images/mars.png" alt="Mars"/>
    </div>
    <div id="jupiter">
        <img src="images/jupiter.png" alt="Jupiter"/>
    </div>
    <div id="saturn">
        <img src="images/saturn.png" alt="Saturn"/>
    </div>
    <div id="uranus">
        <img src="images/uranus.png" alt="Uranus"/>
    </div>
    <div id="neptune">
        <img src="images/neptune.png" alt="Neptune"/>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article.articleTwo img {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    z-index: -2;
}

article.articleTwo div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color .4s ease;
}

article.articleTwo div.hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS

```
$(".articleTwo > div").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("hover");});
```

I think this will do the same but looks a bit more easy.

Comment: After using your code it did not work, but I did manage to make it a lot more concise due to your code. I also changed to class to be click, as it's more fitting

   `$(document).on("click", ".articleTwo > div", function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("click");
    });`